# OSM highway nodes

Tags: xml, openstreetmap

Is there a way to get all the highway nodes from an osm file without using XAPI? I'm trying to use

```
http://xapi.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way[highway=*][bbox=27.5413,47.119,27.678,47.1897]
```

query, but the server doesnt seem to be working. If you can please tell me an XAPI server alternative, or other way to get only the highway nodes, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer

```
http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?way[highway=*][bbox=27.5413,47.119,27.678,47.1897]
```

or [click here](http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?way%5Bhighway=%2a%5D%5Bbbox=27.5413,47.119,27.678,47.1897%5D)

There is lot of other replacements servers providing xapi, you can find them [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/XAPI)